# How can I find a vertex, whose paths to other vertex are the shortest?

Tags: c++, graph, bellman-ford

I have to find the vertex, whose paths to other paths (after summing) are the shortest. I know I can find the shortest path to all from one vertex by using Bellman-Ford algorithm, but I do not know how I can find optimal vertex, whose paths can be the shortest.

Comment: Please refer to : https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: Iterate over vertices, sum distances to all others, keep track of vertex with shortest sum.